# code to insert .animate(variable:'50px'), means animate property as a variable. in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var thetop = "top";

// create the object literal
var aniArgs = {};

// Assign the variable property name with a value of 10
aniArgs[thetop] = 10; 

// Pass the resulting object to the animate method
<something>.stop().animate(
    aniArgs, 10  
);
```

i just want to put top,right,left as a property not the whole thing as in above code

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').stop().animate({top:100, left:100});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in these lines

```
var arg = {};

arg["top"]= "200px";

$('div').animate(arg,2000);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/p3zyK/1/)**